# How to curve Bottom Navigation bar corners without affecting the content in the background? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

I have created a Custom Bottom Navigation Bar with flutter. But I can still see white color filling the background behind the curved corners. I want to see the background content.

This is how the bottom nav bar looks like.

[image]

As you can see, the corners are filled with white color.

This is my code for the bottom nav bar.

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.clear,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(18),
          topRight: Radius.circular(18),
        ),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(color: Colors.black38, spreadRadius: 0, blurRadius: 10),
        ],
      ),
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.085,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(18.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(18.0),
        ),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF0B50F),
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(),
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedPage,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

I tried setting the color of the Container to transparent. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
Scaffold(
    extendBody: true,
```

Comment: It worked sir, thanks! I had to add a ```SizedBox()``` to the bottom of the Scaffold body and add some height because When I added the ```extendBody: true``` line, NavBar stopped taking the space. But it's working perfectly now.

Comment: yep, you need a little bit more work to achieve perfection, good on you!