# flutter rounded corner bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, android-bottomnav

I have a bottom navigation bar inside in ClipRRect (for giving rounded corner). It has rounded corners but no transparent corners. I am sharing image for showing the problem. How can i do transparent rounded corners?

Code:

```
bottomNavigationBar: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
        ),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              label: 'Search',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: 'Profile',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to reference to my answer, [extendBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67431525/how-to-curve-bottom-navigation-bar-corners-without-affecting-the-content-in-the/67431808?noredirect=1#comment119188775_67431808)

```
Scaffold(
  extendBody: true,
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in your theme

```
theme: ThemeData(
    canvasColor: Colors.transparent,)
```

Comment: thanks, i tried this too but scaffold or other widgets don't have a "theme" field.

Comment: it is in your material app